# Upper bound of the jacobstahl function of primorials h(n)

Tags: number-theory

This is following on from my question here: [Maximal gaps in prime factorizations ("wheel factorization")](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664199)

The solution of my problem was the jacobsthal function applied to the product of the first n primes: https://oeis.org/A048670

For instance, for the first 3 primes, you would remove all multiples of 2, 3 and 5 from 1 to 30 and you are left with the set {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}, the maximal gap of which is 6.

For the first 4 primes, you would remove all the multiples of 2,3,5 and 7 from 1 to 210 and you are left with the set {1, 11, 13, 17, .... 199, 209}, the maximal gap of which is 10. When n=5, the maximal gap is 14. When n=6, the maximal gap is 22. And so forth.

I have two additional questions to this.

1) What is the least known upper bound for h(n)? The OEIS page states h(n) << n^2 log log(n). Are there any improved results for this? I tried to read the following papers to answer my question, but unfortunately I am too stupid to understand it! Could anyone else decipher this?

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5944.pdf

http://www.tcnj.edu/~hagedorn/papers/JacobPaper.pdf

http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/37679

2) This function h(n) or the upper bounds for this function are almost always given in terms of the nth prime "n". Are there any results for this in terms of the maximum prime p_k? So for the 5th prime, it wouldn't be in terms of n=5, but p_k=11? Or instead of being in terms of n=7, it in terms of p_k=17

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found another page which may of some use, by Gerhard Paseman (who seems to be an expert on the Jacobsthal function). Unfortunately I didn't understand much of this either. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37679

Answer (score 1):

Another paper I found if anyone's interested.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5342v2.pdf