# Jumps in the consecutive naturals that are relatively prime to the first $n$ primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Claim:** Suppose that $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ are relatively prime to $p_1 p_2 \dots p_n$ (the product of the first $n$ primes). Then if $x$ and $y$ are consecutive, i.e. next to each other when ordered in a sequence, then $|x-y| \leq 2^n$.

I attempt to prove this via induction.

*Proof.*

**Base Case:** Consider the natural numbers rel. prime to $2$. We get the set $\{1,3,5,7, \dots\}$. Then if $x,y \in \{1,3,5,7, \dots\}$ are consecutive, we always have $|x-y| = 2 \leq 2^1$.

**Inductive Step** Suppose the claim (the inductive hypothesis) holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, let $x,y$ be consecutive and rel. prime to $p_1 \dots p_n p_{n+1}$. We have two cases to consider:

*Case 1:* If there does not exist $i \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x < i < y$ so that $i$ is rel. prime to $p_1 \dots p_n$ but not $p_{n+1}$, then we're done by hypothesis. (this essentially means that $x$ and $y$ were consecutive in the sequence of naturals rel. prime to $p_1$ through $p_n$).

*Case 2:* Suppose there is $i \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x < i < y$ so that $i$ is rel. prime to $p_1 \dots p_n$ but not $p_{n+1}$. (this means $i$ was in between $x$ and $y$ in the previous sequence)

Now, since $x$ and $i$ are both rel. prime to $p_1 p_2 \dots p_n$, by hypothesis, we know $|x-i| \leq 2^n$.

It remains to show that $|i-y| \leq 2^n$ so that we can use $|x-y| \leq |x-i| +|i-y| \leq 2^n+2^n = 2^{n+1}$.

Do we know that $|i-y| \leq 2^n$? Clearly, $|x-i| \leq 2^n$ since $i$ follows directly after $x$, but to see that $|y-i| \leq 2^n$ is not nearly as obvious. Any thoughts here?

Comment: You have asked this question over and over and over.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633792/the-maximal-gap-of-the-set-of-numbers-relatively-prime-to-the-product-of-the-fir) for example. Please stop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633792/the-maximal-gap-of-the-set-of-numbers-relatively-prime-to-the-product-of-the-fir

Comment: @lulu you are linking a deleted (and unanswered, for that matter) question. Doesn't this question deserve some attention? It's well thought and well-put, I believe; I am in violation of none of the MathSE Community Guidelines. I'm not sure why this is an offense to the MathSE community.

Comment: In one of the many, many duplicates of this question I proposed that the maximal gap is probably between $1$ and $p_{n+1}$.  Did you try to study that?  I'd be interested in a counterexample, as I mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: @lulu yes,  I did. However, I think $2^n$ will suffice for us. In my last post about this, I made a typo by asserting that the gaps were $2^{n-1}$, an error on my part, I now realize.  While the maximal gap probably is between $1$ and $p_{n+1}$, I think that proving that the gaps are bound by $2^n$ will give a sturdier, more predictable framework and avoid dealing with the slippery distribution of the primes in future work that I do with this claim. This post is a piece of a larger project I'm working on and I'm trying to avoid using primes if possible. Number theory isn't my strong suit

Comment: @lulu also, as I see it, I can't find a counterexample to your claim at the moment. You may be onto something there!

Comment: Who cares?  And it obviously wasn't a typo..[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633128/the-maximal-gap-of-the-set-of-numbers-relatively-prime-to-the-product-of-the-fir) is yet another duplicate in which you make the same blunder.  the distribution of primes is very complicated.  Nobody understands it.  Random guesses about it aren't worth much.   If you had something like a deep search to back up your thoughts, that might be helpful.  But, really, there needs to be something more than what you have shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142725/discussion-between-david-c-huang-and-lulu).

Comment: No, thank you.  $\quad$

Comment: If you are trying to do original research that is beyond the scope of currently known mathematics , mathoverflow is the more appropriate site.

Comment: see  https://oeis.org/A048670

Comment: @lulu   see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5342v2.pdf   which was recommended in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666741/upper-bound-of-the-jacobstahl-function-of-primorials-hn

Comment: David, your desired bound is true, proved by Kanold in 1967.  I put a summary to start my existing answer.  https://eudml.org/doc/161543

Comment: @WillJagy  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a special case of Jacobsthal's function.

The maximal gap you are asking about, relative to the first $n$ primes, is called $h(n).$  The asymptotic upper bound is tiny, Iwaniec showed that, for an unknown positive constant $C,$  that $$   h(n)  \leq  C (n \log n)^2 $$

As far as explicit bounds (no dependence on unknown constants)
Kanold showed that  $$  h(n) \leq 2^n  $$    which is what you wanted.  A very good explicit bound was given by Stevens
$$ h(n) \leq  2 \, n^{2 + 2 e \log n} . $$
This is better than $2^n$  for $n \geq 260.$ It is still far from Iwaniec's bound.

I found  some good stuff by searching for "maximal gaps."   I thought I was on MO  but the closest thing is
[Upper bound of the jacobstahl function of primorials h(n)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666741/upper-bound-of-the-jacobstahl-function-of-primorials-hn)    where he recommended
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5342v2.pdf

https://oeis.org/A048670

https://oeis.org/A048670/b048670.txt

```
2, 4, 6, 10, 14, 22, 26, 34, 40, 46, 58, 66, 74, 90, 100, 106, 118, 132, 152, 174, 190, 200, 216, 234, 258, 264, 282, 300, 312, 330, 354, 378, 388, 414, 432, 450, 476, 492, 510, 538, 550, 574, 600, 616, 642, 660, 686, 718, 742, 762, 798, 810, 834, 858, 876, 908, 926, 954
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:55:17 PM PST
    2    1   -1
   10   11    1

210 =  2 3 5 7
=========================================================
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:55:47 PM PST
    2    1   -1
   12   13    1
   14  127  113

2310 =  2 3 5 7 11
=========================================================
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:56:18 PM PST
    2    1   -1
   16   17    1
   18 2201 2183
   22 9461 9439

30030 =  2 3 5 7 11 13
=========================================================
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:57:39 PM PST
    2         1        -1
   18        19         1
   22      9461      9439
   24     39493     39469
   26    217153    217127

510510 =  2 3 5 7 11 13 17
=========================================================
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:58:28 PM PST
    2         1        -1
   22        23         1
   24      1357      1333
   34     60077     60043

9699690 =  2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
=========================================================
Wed 08 Feb 2023 08:59:32 PM PST
    2         1        -1
   28        29         1
   34     60077     60043
   36   8302493   8302457
   40  20332511  20332471

223092870 =  2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
=========================================================
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$